# Removing a custom domain from an Azure Static Web App

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app

I'm trying to delete two custom domains from my Azure Static Web App. I'm getting notifications saying that the custom domains have been deleted.
But they still are stuck in the list view as *Deleting*.
Tried to delete several times but still they refuse to be removed from the list.

Does anyone know the reason behind this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: In Azure CLI, run the command ```Get-AzStaticWebAppCustomDomain -ResourceGroupName YourRGName -Name StaticWebAppName```. It gives the list of custom domains available for the static webapp.

Comment: Check whether you are getting any custom domains or not .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Sometimes it gets Stucks and takes long time to refresh the list to display the Added or deleted Custom Domains
- We can confirm this by running command in Azure CLI

As per [Get-AzStaticWebAppCustomDomain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/get-azstaticwebappcustomdomain?view=azps-8.2.0) and [Remove-AzStaticWebAppCustomDomain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/remove-azstaticwebappcustomdomain?view=azps-8.2.0) documents ,

To Get the list of Custom Domains of the Static Web App run below Command

```cs
Get-AzStaticWebAppCustomDomain -ResourceGroupName YourRGName -Name StaticWebAppName
```

[image]

- If you are still seeing the custom domains list even after deleting them manually, run the below command to remove them

```cs
Remove-AzStaticWebAppCustomDomain -ResourceGroupName YourRGName -Name StaticWebAppName -DomainName YourdomainName
```

- For me it is shown as Still deleting in progress, but with the `Get-AzStaticWebAppCustomDomain`  I am not able to see the deleted custom domain.
  [image]

Comment: Thanks for putting your effort to this. Unforturnately I'm trying to remove the custom domains as you said but after a while I'm getting this message when running the command.

PS /home/magnus> Remove-AzStaticWebAppCustomDomain -ResourceGroupName rg-xxx -Name swa-xxx-prod -DomainName xxx.xxx.com                
WARNING: Remove-AzStaticWebAppCustomDomain_Delete is not found. The most similar Azure PowerShell command is:
        Remove-AzStaticWebAppCustomDomain
Remove-AzStaticWebAppCustomDomain_Delete: The server responded with an unrecognized response, Status: OK

Comment: Have you tried ```Get-AzStaticWebAppCustomDomain``` command to get the list

Comment: @HarshitaV yes and the custom domains are listed and never goes away. And in the Azure Portal the domains are still showing Deleting in progress even after 24 hours.

Comment: Now, I've got them to disappear. I deleted them once again using the Azure Portal. This time they were removed from the list. The conclusion is that removing a custom domain from an Azure Static Web App can take up to 24 hours to complete.

Comment: Yes, as I have already mentioned it in the answer first point, it takes time to delete the Static web app custom domain and update the list

Comment: Had this happen today and it took 12 hours. Finally ran the Powershell command to remove it and it succeeded, where previous attempts had failed.